# Spark add multiple columns based on conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input Sample Data Set

```
+--------------+----------+-----------+
| col_a        | col_b   |  col_label |
+------------------+-----+------------+
| aa           | hy      | Ford       |
| bb           | NA      | Mahindra   |
|              | my      |  Ford      |
| de           | cz      | Toyota     |
| NA Except xy | mg      |  Hyundai   |
| NA           | gh      |  Toyota    |
+--------------+---------+------------+
```

Expected Output Data Set

```
+--------------+----------+------+------+------------+------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| col_a        | col_b   | col_c | col_d| col_brand  | Ford | Mahindra | Toyota   | Hyundai |  BMW    | AUDI  | Nissan | flag_a | flag_b | flag_ab  |
+--------------+---------+-------+------+------------+------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| aa           | hy      |  aahy |      |  Ford      |  yes |   no     |    no    |   no    |   no    |  no   |   no   |   0    |   0    |   1      |
| bb           | NA      |  bb   |      | Mahindra   |  no  |   yes    |    no    |   no    |   no    |  no   |   no   |   1    |   0    |   0      |
| NA           | my      |  my   |      | Ford       |  yes |   no     |    no    |   no    |   no    |  no   |   no   |   0    |   1    |   0      |
| de           | cz      |  decz |      | Toyota     |  no  |   no     |    yes   |   no    |   no    |  no   |   no   |   0    |   0    |   1      |
| NA except xy | mg      |  mg   |  xy  | Hyundai    |  no  |   no     |    no    |   yes   |   no    |  no   |   no   |   0    |   1    |   0      |
| NA           | gh      |  gh   |      | Toyota     |  no  |   no     |    yes   |   no    |   no    |  no   |   no   |   0    |   1    |   0      |
+--------------+---------+-------+------|------------+------+----------+----------+---------+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Explanation:

column 1. col_a remains as is

column 2.col_b remains as is

column 3. col_c => concat(col_a,col_b). if values with NA or NA except or NULL has to be considered blank("")

column 4. col_d  => capture data anything after "NA except" from col_a

column 5. col_brand remains as is

column 6 till 12 => 
    => static list of brands are Ford,Mahindra,Toyota,Hyundai,BMW,AUDI,Nissan. 
        => compare col_brand with static list of brands (6.1),assign yes or no to the rows appropriately

column 13 till 15 (flag_a, flag_b and flag_ab)
        => Assign 1 or 0 based on values present in col_a and col_b
        => NA / NA except / Null has to be considered blank("")

thank you

Comment: can you explain how you assigning value in flag_a, _b, _ab? what is the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following SQL(through spark-shell) where 'NA' and 'NA except' are case insensitive when setting the temporary flag_a, flag_b(in the CTE) and being used as delimiter to retrieve col_d:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")

spark.sql("""

    WITH t1 AS (
        SELECT IF(col_a = '' OR col_a is NULL, 'NA', col_a) as col_a
        ,      IF(col_b = '' OR col_b is NULL, 'NA', col_b) as col_b
        ,      IF(col_a rlike '^(?i)NA(?:\\s+except\\b|$)' OR col_a = '' OR col_a is NULL, 0, 1) as flag_a
        ,      IF(col_b rlike '^(?i)NA(?:\\s+except\\b|$)' OR col_b = '' OR col_b is NULL, 0, 1) as flag_b
        ,      col_label as col_brand
        FROM df_table
    )
    SELECT col_a
    ,      col_b
    ,      concat(IF(flag_a > 0, col_a, ''), IF(flag_b > 0, col_b, '')) as col_c
    ,      coalesce(split(col_a, '(?i)NA except ')[1], '') as col_d
    ,      col_brand
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'Ford', 'yes', 'no') as Ford
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'Mahindra', 'yes', 'no') as Mahindra
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'Toyota', 'yes', 'no') as Toyota
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'Hyundai', 'yes', 'no') as Hyundai
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'BMW', 'yes', 'no') as BMW
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'AUDI', 'yes', 'no') as AUDI
    ,      IF(col_brand = 'Nissan', 'yes', 'no') as Nissan
    ,      IF(flag_a = 1 AND flag_b = 0, 1, 0) as flag_a
    ,      IF(flag_a = 0 AND flag_b = 1, 1, 0) as flag_b
    ,      IF(flag_a = 1 AND flag_b = 1, 1, 0) as flag_ab
    FROM t1

""").show
+------------+-----+-----+-----+---------+----+--------+------+-------+---+----+------+------+------+-------+
|       col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|col_brand|Ford|Mahindra|Toyota|Hyundai|BMW|AUDI|Nissan|flag_a|flag_b|flag_ab|
+------------+-----+-----+-----+---------+----+--------+------+-------+---+----+------+------+------+-------+
|          aa|   hy| aahy|     |     Ford| yes|      no|    no|     no| no|  no|    no|     0|     0|      1|
|          bb|   NA|   bb|     | Mahindra|  no|     yes|    no|     no| no|  no|    no|     1|     0|      0|
|          NA|   my|   my|     |     Ford| yes|      no|    no|     no| no|  no|    no|     0|     1|      0|
|          de|   cz| decz|     |   Toyota|  no|      no|   yes|     no| no|  no|    no|     0|     0|      1|
|NA Except xy|   mg|   mg|   xy|  Hyundai|  no|      no|    no|    yes| no|  no|    no|     0|     1|      0|
|          NA|   gh|   gh|     |   Toyota|  no|      no|   yes|     no| no|  no|    no|     0|     1|      0|
+------------+-----+-----+-----+---------+----+--------+------+-------+---+----+------+------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object sampleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    val df = Seq(("aa","hy","Ford"),("bb","NA","Manindra"),("","my","Ford"),("de","cz","Toyota"),
        ("NA Except xy","mg","Hyundai"),("NA","gf","Toyota")).toDF("col_a","col_b","col_brand")

    val chkrules = udf((a:String) =>{
      //println("before")
      val a1= (a.toLowerCase.contains("na") || a.toLowerCase.contains("except") || a.toLowerCase.contains("between")) match {
        case true => ""
        case false => a
      }
      a1
    })
    def generateArr(n: Int) = {
      if (n <= 0) Array.empty[String]
      var arr: Array[String] = Array()
      arr = arr :+ "0" :+ "1"
      var i: Int = 0
      var j: Int = 0
      i = 2
      while (i < (1 << n)) {
        j = i - 2
        while (j <= 1) {
          arr = arr :+ arr(j)
          j += 1
        }
        j = 0
        while (j < i) {
          arr(j)= arr(j) + "0"
          j += 1
        }
        j = i
        while (j < 2 * i) {
          arr(j) = arr(j) + "1"
          j += 1
        }
        i = i << 1
      }
      arr.filter(_!="00")
    }
    def create_flg(n_size:Int,cols: String) = {
      val flgBin = generateArr(n_size)
      val colsArr = cols.split(",")

      (flgBin zip colsArr.toIterable).zipWithIndex.map { case (c_flg, i) => (i+1, c_flg._1, c_flg._2) }

    }


    val flgValues = create_flg(2,"col_a,col_b,col_ab") //output: Array((1,"10","col_a"),(2,"01","col_b"),(3,"11","col_ab")

    val flgClms = Seq("flg_a","flg_b","flg_ab").zipWithIndex

    val flgChk = udf((a:String,b:String) =>{
      val ar = Seq(a,b)
      val a1 = ar.map(x =>
        (x.toLowerCase.contains("na") || x.toLowerCase.contains("except") || x.toLowerCase.contains("between")|| x.trim == "") match {
        case true => 0
        case false => 1
      }) //output: 00 or 10 or 01 or 11
      val out = flgValues.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map(kv => {
      kv._2 == a1.mkString("") match {
          case true => 1
          case false => 0
        }
      })
      out
    })

    println("Input:")
    df.show(false)
    val finaldf = df.withColumn("col_c",concat(chkrules($"col_a"),chkrules($"col_b")))
  .withColumn("col_d",regexp_extract($"col_a",".*NA Except\\s*([^\n\r]*)",1)).withColumn("flg",flgChk($"col_a",$"col_b"))
    println("Creating flg column")
    finaldf.show(false)
    val clms = finaldf.columns.map(z => z == "flg" match{
      case false => Seq(col(z))
      case true => flgClms.map { case (i,j) => col(z).getItem(j).as(i)}

    })

    //finaldf.select(clms.flatten:+ $"flg" :_*).show(false)
    val final_df_pivot = finaldf.groupBy(clms.flatten:_*)
      .pivot("col_brand").agg(coalesce(first(lit("yes")),lit("no")))


    println("Output:")
    final_df_pivot.show(false)
  }
}

Input:
+------------+-----+---------+
|col_a       |col_b|col_brand|
+------------+-----+---------+
|aa          |hy   |Ford     |
|bb          |NA   |Manindra |
|            |my   |Ford     |
|de          |cz   |Toyota   |
|NA Except xy|mg   |Hyundai  |
|NA          |gf   |Toyota   |
+------------+-----+---------+
Creating flg column:
+------------+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+
|col_a       |col_b|col_brand|col_c|col_d|flg      |
+------------+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+
|aa          |hy   |Ford     |aahy |     |[0, 0, 1]|
|bb          |NA   |Manindra |bb   |     |[1, 0, 0]|
|            |my   |Ford     |my   |     |[0, 1, 0]|
|de          |cz   |Toyota   |decz |     |[0, 0, 1]|
|NA Except xy|mg   |Hyundai  |mg   |xy   |[0, 1, 0]|
|NA          |gf   |Toyota   |gf   |     |[0, 1, 0]|
+------------+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+
Output:
+------------+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+-------+--------+------+
|col_a       |col_b|col_brand|col_c|col_d|flg_a|flg_b|flg_ab|Ford|Hyundai|Manindra|Toyota|
+------------+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+-------+--------+------+
|NA Except xy|mg   |Hyundai  |mg   |xy   |0    |1    |0     |no  |yes    |no      |no    |
|bb          |NA   |Manindra |bb   |     |1    |0    |0     |no  |no     |yes     |no    |
|aa          |hy   |Ford     |aahy |     |0    |0    |1     |yes |no     |no      |no    |
|            |my   |Ford     |my   |     |0    |1    |0     |yes |no     |no      |no    |
|de          |cz   |Toyota   |decz |     |0    |0    |1     |no  |no     |no      |yes   |
|NA          |gf   |Toyota   |gf   |     |0    |1    |0     |no  |no     |no      |yes   |
+------------+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+-------+--------+------+
```